# Performance issues on SQL query with similar subselects

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a complex SQL query that works, but its performance is less than ideal (it takes almost 3 seconds to perform). I guess I optimized everything I could think of, but maybe there is something more that  I still can not catch.

Here it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT doctors.doc_id, doctors.doc_title, doctors.doc_last, 
    doctors.doc_first, doctors.doc_email, doctors.doc_birthday,
    doctors.doc_mobile, doctors.doc_occasional, doctors.doc_fiscal_code, 
    doctors.doc_register_number, doctors.doc_register_province, 
    doctors.doc_agreement, doctors.doc_notes, doctors.doc_timestamp,
    doctors.doc_deleted, specializations.spe_id, specializations.spe_name,
    activities.act_id, activities.act_name,
    users.use_id, users.use_last, users.use_first, users.use_active,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM congress
    INNER JOIN participants ON participants.par_congress = congress.cng_id
    WHERE par_doctor = doc_id
    AND congress.cng_from >= '2018-01-01'
    AND congress.cng_from <= '2018-07-02')
    AS cng_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM visits
    INNER JOIN reports ON reports.rep_id = visits.vis_report
    INNER JOIN locations ON locations.loc_id = visits.vis_location
    WHERE visits.vis_doctor = doctors.doc_id 
    AND locations.loc_structure LIKE '%' 
    AND reports.rep_dated >= '2018-01-01' 
    AND reports.rep_dated <= '2018-07-02')
    AS vis_count_all,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM visits
    INNER JOIN reports ON reports.rep_id = visits.vis_report
    INNER JOIN locations ON locations.loc_id = visits.vis_location 
    WHERE visits.vis_doctor = doctors.doc_id 
    AND reports.rep_user = users.use_id 
    AND locations.loc_structure LIKE '%' 
    AND reports.rep_dated >= '2018-01-01' 
    AND reports.rep_dated <= '2018-07-02')
    AS vis_count_user,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM locations
    WHERE locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id )
    AS loc_count
    FROM doctors
    LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.loc_doctor = doctors.doc_id
    INNER JOIN specializations ON specializations.spe_id = doctors.doc_specialization
    INNER JOIN activities ON activities.act_id = doctors.doc_activity
    INNER JOIN users ON users.use_id = doctors.doc_user 
    WHERE doctors.doc_last IS NOT NULL 
    AND doctors.doc_id LIKE '%' 
    AND (locations.loc_province IS NULL OR locations.loc_province LIKE '%') 
    AND (locations.loc_structure IS NULL OR locations.loc_structure LIKE '%') 
    AND DATE(doctors.doc_timestamp) <= '2018-07-02' 
    AND doctors.doc_occasional LIKE '%' 
    AND doctors.doc_deleted LIKE '0' 
    AND doctors.doc_agreement LIKE '%' 
    AND doctors.doc_active 
    AND users.use_id LIKE '%' 
    GROUP BY doctors.doc_id 
    HAVING vis_count_user <> - 1 
    ORDER BY doctors.doc_last, doctors.doc_first, doctors.doc_id
```

The real bottleneck is on the `vis_count_all` and `vis_count_user` subselects (they differ only for an additional `AND reports.rep_user = users.use_id` statement): removing them speeds up query

Since they differ only in a statement, I don't know if I can reuse one of them to get the other value in a simpler way

Anyway, I created all the keys I could think of, here is the EXPLAIN result

[image]

Please, any advice on improvements?
Thank you

Comment: Please remove anything from the query that doesn't make it slow.

Answer (score 0):

This 'covering' index may help some:

```
visits:  (vis_doctor, vis_report, vis_location)
```

It would probably be better to remove useless clauses such as those containing `LIKE '%'`.  Related to that,

```
          AND  (locations.loc_province IS NULL
              OR  locations.loc_province LIKE '%')
```

is probably very poorly optimized.  Plan A:  Remove it.  Plan B:  avoid using `NULL` for whatever.

Having both `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` raises a red flag.  Adding `DISTINCT` is just plain 'wrong'.  Please decide whether you need either `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`.  I don't think you need either.  Certainly don't use both.

What??

```
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) AS vis_count_user
 HAVING vis_count_user <> -1
```

The `HAVING` does nothing other than slow down the query.

```
AND  DATE(doctors.doc_timestamp) <= '2018-07-02'
```

Hiding a column in a function prevents use of an index.  BTW, what are the indexes?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  This has the same semantics:

```
AND  doctors.doc_timestamp < '2018-07-02' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Did you really mean to have 6 months, plus 1 (or 2?) day:

```
AND reports.rep_dated >= '2018-01-01' 
AND reports.rep_dated <= '2018-07-02'
```

Consider

```
AND reports.rep_dated >= '2018-01-01' 
AND reports.rep_dated  < '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

Comment: Hi Rick, and sorry for the late reply: unfortunately i need all the stuff I posted: since it's used in a PHP page search engine, the `LIKE '%'` are dynamic, as the `HAVING vis_count_user <> -1` and the `AND reports.rep_dated >= '2018-01-01' `.
I'll try to work on `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`, but for the rest I need all of these :-(

Comment: When constructing a `SELECT` in PHP from user input, I like to "build up" the query.  Rather than defaulting to `LIKE '%'`, I simply avoid adding the test for that clause to the `WHERE`.  In your case, leaving it out will (probably) speed up the query significantly.